# Is there a way to constrain music21's chord detection to non-slash chords?

Tags: python, music21, music-notation

I'm working on a script that takes as input a sequence of MIDI notes and outputs a chord symbol for use in Impro-Visor, an open-source jazz improvisation helper. In order to take advantage of Impro-Visor's large vocabulary of chords I've been trying to add to music21's chord vocabulary--music21 itself will handle the MIDI pitches and the interpretation of most common chords--using the `harmony.addNewChordSymbol` method, but the system doesn't offer the new chords in its chord detection. For example, if I try this chord from the Harmony module's docs:

```
>>>harmony.addNewChordSymbol('BethChord', '1,3,-6,#9', ['MH', 'beth'])
>>>c = chord.Chord(['C3','D#3','E3','A-3'])
>>>print(harmony.chordSymbolFromChord(c))
'A-+/CaddD#'
```

Whereas I would hope in this case to get: `'Cbeth'`

Music21 consistently suggests slash chords like the above rather than whatever chord I've tried to add to the vocabulary, presumably because the chord type to the left of the slash--'+', in this case--comes earlier in the OrderedDict in harmony.py. Is there any way to make the chord-detection prefer a custom chord type over these slash chords (which I don't have any way of handling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that just telling `music21` you meant for "C" to be the root does the trick. (Otherwise, it will try to stack in thirds and treat "Ab" as the root.) Call `.root()` like this:

```
>>> harmony.addNewChordSymbol('BethChord', '1,3,-6,#9', ['MH', 'beth'])
>>> c = chord.Chord(['C3','D#3','E3','A-3'])
>>> c.root(c.bass())
>>> harmony.chordSymbolFromChord(c)
<music21.harmony.ChordSymbol CMH>
```